# List the total power consumed for a given metal in the last one hour of the process

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. Metal master table has actual metal start and end timestamps. The Metal interval table has the electricity reading for a specific timestamp. The power for a specific time interval is the cumulative difference in electricity consumed for all the readings with
in the time interval from the Metal Interval data. I'm trying to get the list the total power consumed for a given metal in the last one hour of the process. Can you help me with this?

Here is the sample table:

Metal_Interval_Data

```
MetalID TreatID Plant   ElctrctyConsumed    ReadingTime 
123456  8       MEAF    21500        2017-07-01 14:01:34.34
123456  8       MEAF    21650        2017-07-01 14:01:44.44
123456  8       MEAF    0            2017-07-01 09:54:53.53
123478  8       MEAF    0            2017-07-01 23:37:19.19
123478  8       MEAF    150          2017-07-02 00:32:08.08
```

Metal_Master_Data

```
MetalID MetalStartActual        MetalStartPlanned       MetalEndActual   MetalEndPlanned
123456  2017-07-01 09:51:42.42  2017-06-30 08:59:35.35  2017-07-01 16:05:33.33  2017-06-30 14:59:35.35
123478  2017-07-01 23:30:31.31  2017-06-30 20:00:00.00  2017-07-02 00:33:25.25  2017-06-30 20:59:59.59
124302  2017-07-02 01:42:42.42  2017-07-01 20:51:47.47  2017-07-02 02:17:14.14  2017-07-01 21:51:47.47
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't what you tried work? What is the expected results for the data you've provided?

Comment: @BharathKumar . . . "all the readings with in the time interval from the Metal Interval data".  One table has one timestamp.  The other has four.  I have no idea how the data relates to this description.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MetalStartActual and MetalEndActual is used to get the electricity consumed within the time interval. other two timestamps can be ignored.

Comment: @BharathKumar could you please add the expected output?

Comment: So you want the sum by metal of ElctrctyConsumed where ReadingTime within MetalEndActual and (MetalEdActaul -1) ?

Comment: (MetalEndActual - 1 hour) I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following script-

```
SELECT A.MetalID,SUM(B.ElctrctyConsumed) TotalConsumed
FROM Metal_Master_Data A
INNER JOIN Metal_Interval_Data B ON A.MetalID = B.MetalID
WHERE B.ReadingTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HH,-1,A.MetalEndActual) AND A.MetalEndActual
GROUP BY A.MetalID
```

Answer (score 1):

@mkRabbani is correct but it specific for a given metal id

```
SELECT A.MetalID,SUM(B.ElctrctyConsumed) TotalConsumed
FROM Metal_Master_Data A
INNER JOIN Metal_Interval_Data B ON A.MetalID = B.MetalID
WHERE B.ReadingTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HH,-1,A.MetalEndActual) 
AND A.MetalEndActual and A.MetalID=@givenmetalid
GROUP BY A.MetalID
```